# Error collating elements post collating elements not supported regexp

Tags: php, mysql, regex, laravel

I get this error while trying to insall system created with laravel. Any idea ?

Error collating elements post collating elements not supported regexp

```
        $data = DB::select('SHOW TABLES WHERE '.$name.' NOT REGEXP "[[.low-line.]]"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly because `$name` contains an invalid character. May be `-`.

You can solve this problem by surrounding with backtick:

```
$data = DB::select('SHOW TABLES WHERE `'.$name.'` NOT REGEXP "[[.low-line.]]"');
//                             here __^   and __^
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `SHOW TABLES` is not the same as for `SELECT`.

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'm%';
```

No REGEXP, etc.

You can look in this table with a `SELECT`:  `information_schema.TABLES` .